# html spacing inside the table

Tags: html, spacing

how can i increase the space in this table "Row 1, cell 1"?

```
 <html>
 <table border="1">
 <tr>
 <td>Row 1, cell 1</td>
 <td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
 </tr>
 </table>  
 </html>
```

pls check here for the image: 
http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/6166/htmln.png

is this correct:

```
 <table border="1" td.my-cell { padding:100px; }>
<tr>
<td class="my-cell">Row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "increase the space"? Do you want the first table cell to be wider?

Comment: yes. sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use [cellpadding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellpadding.asp) or using css

```
.cellpadding {
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-right: 5px;
}

<td class="cellpadding">Row 1, cell 1</td>
```

---

**EDIT** Your edited post is wrong....do this:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">Row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this is great help The Elite Gentleman ;-) Can I also use padding-bottom here?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to that specific cell and then use that class-name to apply css:

```
.larger {
height: 2em;
width: 4em;
padding: 2em;
}

<!-- rest of table -->
<td class="larger">Row 1, cell 1</td>
<!-- rest of table -->
```

Or you could use specific style-rules to apply a particular style:

```
tr td:first-child /* selects the first td within a tr */
```

Though this would apply to the first `td` of *every* row.

Answer (score 0):

elaborate on "space"? you can add padding to the td if thats what you mean by "space"

`table td { padding:5px; }`

if you just want that cell bigger, add a calss

`table td.my-cell { padding:5px; }`

`<td class="my-cell">Row 1, cell 1</td>`

or do you mean

`<td>`Row 1,           cell1`</td>`

you can increase the space between words like this:

`table td { word-spacing: 20px; /* adjust */ }`